# React cannot access multidimensional array state value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

In my react application I am setting the state value as an array using the below code.

```
const [ds_data, setDsData] = useState([]);
    let ds_arr = res.data.map((elem, index) => {
                  return elem.split(" ")
                })
                setDsData(ds_arr)
```

The values in the array when I use console.log(ds_arr) are

[image]

The value I am getting from the server is given below.
[image]

The problem is when I try to display the value of the multidimensional array using `{ds_data[0][0]}`, I am getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

in the console. When I used `{ds_data[0]}` it is showing all the array values as a single string:

```
363861319e9d5720089762a51d24a86dd1402dbba64771c9
```

The data is displayed inside a bootstrap modal component

Comment: The image shows `console.log` of what?

Comment: I can not recreate the problem from your example. React is setting and reading nested arrays just fine for me. It might be helpful to share more code of what is setting and reading `ds_data` ♥

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava ds_arr variable

Comment: @asyncawait I am doing a Axios call, the response of which is res.data

Comment: Maybe you're trying to access the data before your Axios call resolves? is your log after the fetch probably in a useEffect statement?

Comment: Then how it is showing as a string value? I use the log before the return statement of functional component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the state was not set initially, so I have to check if the state was set using the code `{Array.isArray(ds_data) && Array.isArray(ds_data[0]) ? ds_data[0][0] : ""}`